# Can I use onclick event and contextmenu for single view?

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application i need to use both the `onClick` and `contextmenu` for single view it's working fine but if i longclicked for context menu i am not able to performing onclick on a perticular view. please any one help me regarding this issue.

Comment: You better use onItemClick & onItemLongClick

Comment: use flag to handle event

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use onTouch insteed?

```
protected boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    long past;
    long now;

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        past = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // do nothing here
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - past < 3000) {
            // a click, do what ever you want here
        }
        else if (now - past >= 3000) {
            // longclick, do what ever you want here
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Oh nice way of handling that, +1